# why does tomcat take time to recognize the folder on shutting down and restarting it?

Tags: tomcat6, restart, shutdown

I work on a folder and tomcat recognizes the folder. But, when I shutdown and restart tomcat it is taking time to recognize the same folder. Can anybody tell me why?

I see the error report in catalina.out. It gives a list of errors but finally says
Nov 22, 2009 2:08:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1403 ms

Comment: What does it mean to "recognize the folder"? What folder? What does "recognize" mean?

Comment: Is the 'folder' your webapp? And does 'recognize' mean that your webapp becomes available (started)?

Comment: By recognize I mean that index.html is opened on typing http://hostname:port/test
test is a folder in webapps and index.html is in test

Answer (score 0):

I pressume 'folder' is your webapp. I takes time starting your wabapp, because tomcat has to load.parse configuration files for that app. Additionaly if your webapp contains JSP pages those get most likely recompiled on the restart.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to application deployment time. The most time consuming process is to scan the jars for TLDs. If you don't use JSP tags, you can speed up the deployment time by adding this to your context,

```
  <Context processTlds="false" ... />
```